# Redirect people who visit from a specific link to another page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a situation where A.com always link to my products, and then have their visitors come check it out, and then discussing it.

I do not want this, nore am I interested in their pointless visits, which just eats away at my bandwidth.

I want to manually place a code in my product page's header, or .htaccess file, that would redirect  A.com, back to A.com, or to google.com

A typical link where they all come from is in this format:

forum.A.com/showthread.php?t=1111111

I know you can do it with this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} badsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

But i do not wish to show a "FORBIDDEN" message. I just want to kindly show them on their way away from my site.

**SOLUTION**:

```
<?php
    $HTTP_REFERRER=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
    if ($HTTP_REFERRER) { 
    // check if the referrer is on your noentry list 
    // if so redirect it to another page 
        if ($HTTP_REFERRER == "http://website.com") { 
           header("Location: http://gotothiswebsiteinstead.com");
            die(); 
        } 
    } else { 
    //everything is OK 
    }

?>
```

Comment: Why not just send them back to the referrer?

Comment: Sure, but i'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I believe it's just `RewriteRule ^*$ %{HTTP_REFERER}`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do exactly what you want:

```
$refererHost = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PARSE_URL_HOST);
if (preg_match('/^(www\.)?badhost\.com$/i', $refererHost)) {
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    die();
}
```

**However**, be aware that anyone could fake their referer.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try that out now. Do you mind putting this link in this format?   forum.A.com/showthread.php?t=1111111    I'm having a difficult time decoding how it has to fit in with all those characters and slashes.